# How many takedown techniques exist in Judo

Tags: judo, throwing, takedown

I would like know if some one know how many takedowns exist in Judo ?

I know a few years ago, the International Olympic Committee changed the rules for some takedowns. If I'm right, now is not more allow hold the pants to start a takedown.

Before this changes. What is the total number of techniques ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Kodokan still recognizes [67 official throwing techniques](http://judoinfo.com/gokyo.htm), but not all of them are allowed in competition, and some of them have been banned in competition for some time.

The whole classification of throws is a messy business. The differentiating points are sometimes rather arcane: why does it matter if tori is holding the belt or not in performing a hip throw if the positioning and throwing action are otherwise the same? And some throws that really seem quite different are classified as being the same, like kouchi gari and kouchi makikomi. So while the throws in competition usage continue to evolve, the classification bins they fit into change only slowly. Because of this I am not sure whether the answer to your question is useful, but we can go through the exercise anyway.

Banned due to injury risk:

1. kani basami
2. kawazu gake

Banned due to rule change about touching legs:

1. morote gari
2. kuchiki taoshi
3. kibisu gaeshi
4. kata guruma? I have seen a version of kata guruma that would seem to satisfy both the shoulder wheel and not touching below the belt with the arms or hands. Whether the Kodokan calls it kata guruma is open to question.

So `67 - (5 or 6)` gives 62 or 61.

Also remember that the International Judo Federation is in the habit of tweaking the rules every year, so in 6 months this may change anyway.

Comment: **Note:** since this answer was posted the Kodokan has added obi-tori-gaeshi and kouchi-maki-komi, and removed daki-age (as of [2017](http://kodokanjudoinstitute.org/en/news/2017/04/names-of-judo-technique/)).